# Laravel 5.3 - Internal redirect or modify request middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am building an API with Laravel 5.3. I have routes such as `/users/1`, `users/1/teams` etc.

I'd like client applications to also be able to use URIs like `/users/self`, `/users/self/teams`.

I was looking into building a middleware that checks to see if `/self/` is in the request URI and if it is, then change `/self/` to the user's actual id, or do an internal redirect to the requested endpoint.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Could you post some code and show an attempt, please. We could then try to help you understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: Format paths to be more readable

Answer (score 1):

Create middleware and use it:

1) create middleware:

file: `app/Http/Middleware/ReplaceSelfToId.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ReplaceSelfToId
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->route('id') == 'self') { // if id is self
          if(!$request->user()) { // but user not instantiated
            return redirect()->route('auth'); // redirect to auth
          }
          $request->route()->setParameter('id',  $request->user()->id); // replace id to user's id
        }   
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2) register middleware in `Kernel.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use App\Http\Middleware\ReplaceSelfToId; // use middleware
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        ReplaceSelfToId::class   // add this line to end of array (cuz have to get session initialized)
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your request is not a very good practice, you should not touch it, so why don't you just create a users repository and do that in there?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UsersRepository
{
    private $auth;

    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
        if ($id == 'self') {
            return Auth::user();
        }

        return User::find($id);
    }
}
```

And use it in your controllers

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class Games extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @var UsersRepository
     */
    private $usersRepository;

    public function __construct(UsersRepository $usersRepository)
    {
        $this->usersRepository = $usersRepository;
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return view('show', ['user' => $this->usersRepository->findById($id)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the use of `private $auth;` (and all sugar around) if you don't use it?